# Does the compiler optimize string concatenation?

Tags: string, delphi, delphi-xe2, concatenation, compiler-optimization

I have some cases in my code where I am building a large string of text, such as a complex SQL statement. I intend to put this text together many times in a row, each with some slightly different parameters. I've come to the habit of using a subroutine named just `procedure A(const S: String);` which simply appends the text (`S`) to the larger string `Text := Text + S + #10 + #13;`

I was wondering if this could hinder the performance as opposed to using traditional string concatenation? I am beginning to think the compiler optimizes something like this:

```
Text := 'some' + ' ' + 'text' + ' ' + 'and' + ' ' + 'such';
```

to

```
Text := 'some text and such';
```

Is this true? Does the compiler optimize this scenario? If so, I may decide to change everything to something like this:

```
Text := 'select something from sometable st'+#10+#13+
  'join someothertable sot on sot.id = st.sotid'+#10+#13+
  'where sot.somevalue = 1'+#10+#13+
  'order by sot.sorting';
```

Would this be faster theoretically than

```
Text:= Text + 'select something from sometable st'+#10+#13;
Text:= Text + 'join someothertable sot on sot.id = st.sotid'+#10+#13;
Text:= Text + 'where sot.somevalue = 1'+#10+#13;
Text:= Text + 'order by sot.sorting';
```

or how I usually do it:

```
A('select something from sometable st');
A('join someothertable sot on sot.id = st.sotid');
A('where sot.somevalue = 1');
A('order by sot.sorting');
```

Comment: Why not just open it in the debugger and look at the generated ASM?

Comment: Because I don't understand ASM, I go blank when I look at it :P

Comment: This question is a perfect example of how "cleaning up code" sometimes leads to more critical flaws in the project's performance.

Comment: If you are going to send that text as a SQL query, then the db query will take many orders of magnitude more time than the code to create the query string.

Comment: Or an XML packet, which is another scenario I use. And no, I don't wish to use any type of XML class when I'm writing an XML file.

Comment: Just curious: why are you using #10#13 (LF CR) instead of #13#10 (CR LF)?

Comment: Use sLineBreak and don't have to remember which is first..

Comment: Completely unrelated but why don't you use paratemerized SQL queries? I think you can get much more performance increase out of that then worrying about string concatenation.

Comment: That SQL query is just a quick sample of a real-life scenario. The code behind the query is completely fake and is in no way associated with any work of mine.

Comment: >>"That SQL query is just a quick sample of a real-life scenario." In that case, I want to make more clear what has been noted here. Please consider Knuth: "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small inefficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An expression like

```
'a' + 'b'
```

is evaluated at compile time. Which means that an assignment

```
str := 'a' + 'b';
```

results in identical compiled code to

```
str := 'ab';
```

On the other hand, for

```
str := 'a';
str := str + 'b';
```

the concatenation is performed at runtime.

Comment: That's exactly what I was hoping and expecting, just had to hear it from someone more knowledgeable, thanks!

Comment: This is one of the "peephole optimizations" which is named "constant folding". See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding Delphi compiler does not implement all those optimizations, but the most common and useful one. The good thing is that I've never seen Delphi optimization fails the code logic, whereas some aggressive compilers sometimes do not have a consistent behavior in case of optimization settings.

Comment: Very nice.  It makes a very long inline string written as a series of concatenation as efficient as a "here document" or "multiline string literal" that is possible in languages like Perl and Python.

Answer (score 0):

Note that putting all concatenations in one expression is still more efficient when non-constant expressions are used. 
Consider this code:

```
  A := '*';
  B := 'person';
  C := 'first_name=''Jerry''';

  Q := 'select ';
  Q := Q + A;
  Q := Q + ' from ';
  Q := Q + B;
  Q := Q + ' where ';
  Q := Q + C;
```

The six statements above will perform 5 separate concatenations.
Whereas:

```
  Q := 'select ' + A + ' from ' + B + ' where ' + C;
```

will perform a single concatenation. Delphi will allocate the necessary space for the result and copy each of the six values into that space.